# Creating a self-signed bundle of SSL certificate files

Tags: ssl

I ran the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt
```

and it created localhost.key and localhost.crt, but I also need localhost.bundle.crt and localhost.csr.

How do I create the other two? Right now, I just made the files and copied the content of localhost.key into localhost.csr and localhost.bundle.crt.

I am thinking it doesn't matter what I put in those files, because I am going to use them for a staging environment I just set up. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You've created a self-signed certificate using a single command.

Another way to create it is to generate an intermediate Certificate Signing Request (`.csr`) file first, then sign it with another OpenSSL command.  The end result is the same - `localhost.crt`.  Unless you're sending your certificate request to a CA to be signed, then you don't need the `.csr` file.  If you are sending the request to a CA, then you've simply used the wrong command and have generated a certificate instead of a certificate signing request.

A bundle is a collection of certificates and is required when you have more than a single self-signed certificate.  That is, if you have a CA and an end-entity (a web-server for example) you can create a bundle of both certificates which is then used by the end-entity.  Creating a bundle of one certificate results in an identical file to the `localhost.crt` you've already created.  If you really, really, really want one, then `cp localhost.crt localhost.bundle.crt` would do :-)   If you did intend to create a certificate signing request and send it to a CA for signing, then you'll hopefully receive the bundle back from the CA.